# ActiveSalesforce + Heroku + PostgreSQL + Rails 2.3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, salesforce

How to setup my Rails app so it will be able to use both Salesforce and PostgreSQL as a backend on Heroku. My current code is:

```
#environment.rb 
...
config.gem "asf-soap-adapter", :lib => 'asf-soap-adapter'
config.database_configuration_file = File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'config', 'salesforce.yml')
```

salesforce.yml contains config for both PostgreSQL and SF. This doesn't work because it replaces current Heroku database.yml, so I am not able to connect to DB.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it seams that I have figured it out:
All you need to do is to create a separate config file for backends, e.g. "**salesforce.yml**", which looks like this:

```
development:
  # usual stuff that you put at your database.yml

test:
  # usual stuff that you put at your database.yml

production:
  # you need to get following from Heroku (http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database#database_urls)
  host: #host of Herkou db
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: # Heroku db name
  username: # Heroku db username
  password: # Heroku db password

salesforce-default-realm:
  adapter: activesalesforce
  url: https://www.salesforce.com
  username: #salesforce username
  password: #{salesforce_password}{salesforce_security_token}
  api_version: 20.0
```

Then **environment.rb:**

```
...
config.gem "asf-soap-adapter", :lib => 'asf-soap-adapter'
config.database_configuration_file = File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'config', 'salesforce.yml')
```